# How do I modify paths and change to a real path?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, udev, paths

I am a beginner at Ubuntu. I am wanting to install my-udev-notify, and I was able to follow these instructions in the README.md file:

> Installation 
>   ------------ 
>   
>   - unpack archive somewhere in your system 
>   - copy file `./stuff/my-udev-notify.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d`

However, when I came across this:

> - modify paths in it: change `/path/to/my-udev-notify/my-udev-notify.sh` to 
>   real path to the `my-udev-notify.sh` script (where you unpacked it).

I was confused. I tried looking up how to modify paths, but I have seen some different answers, and I am not sure how to correctly perform this task in this situation. Please let me know what I should do and fully explain what the terminal commands that are necessary to perform this task do step-by-step.

Comment: Give me the name of the archive and the location where it is: the exact path to the folder. Something like Home/Downloads or wherever it is. Then I'll post you a step by step answer for your issue...

Comment: @Neni The unpacked archive directory is /home/imnebuddy/Software/Other/Compressed/my-udev-notify/dfrank-my-udev-notify-0d78b20a38e8/my-udev-notify.sh, and the location path needed to be changed is /path/to/my-udev-notify/my-udev-notify.sh. I followed the installation instructions exactly as said above.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `my-udev-notify.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d` and open it with `gedit` using `gksudo`, you may install `gksu` first:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
sudo cp -iv ./stuff/my-udev-notify.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/my-udev-notify.rules
```

Once opened, just **replace** in both lines `/path/to/my-udev-notify/my-udev-notify.sh` with your path `/home/imnebuddy/Software/Other/Compressed/my-udev-notify/dfrank-my-udev-notify-0‌​d78b20a38e8/my-udev-notify.sh`. You can do it with Copy-Paste.

Save and Exit.

Now copy the cofiguration file as described in `README.md` and edit it. Replace `/path/to/some/sound_file` with the paths to the sound files in the *sound* directory which is located in the same directory as the *stuff* directory. At the end, reboot your system:

```
sudo cp -iv ./stuff/config_example/my-udev-notify.conf /etc/my-udev-notify.conf
gksudo gedit /etc/my-udev-notify.conf
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps it's saying to modify the path in a configuration file that you installed, since it says "modify paths in it"; presumably, "it" is referring to the previously mentioned file, probably `/etc/udev/rules.d` since it was the last file mentioned. You need to edit this file using an editor such as gedit.  If it is in the`/etc/udev` directory, which is owned by root, then you will need to run gedit using the `gksudo` command:

```
  gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d
```

This is a common way for programs to read their own configuration settings.  The path is only for the system to find executable files.

However, if you need to modify the path, here's a general guideline on how to do it...

**Where to modify the path**

For shells affecting only a specific user (such as yourself), `~/.profile` seems to be the correct place to modify it.  For all users, I believe it needs to be set in `/etc/profile`.

**How to modify it**

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/be/added
export PATH
```

Comment: So how would I type the commands to indicate the unpacked location and the "real path"? I see /path/to/be/added, but that is only one location. Don't I need to type both directories in some way for this modification to work?

Comment: @NAE: What 2 directories are you referring to?  I only see it wanting one, the path to the file "my-udev-notify.sh"; it doesn't know where that was put by you.  "/path/to/be/added" is only a made up example; you don't put that anywhere, you put "/home/imnebuddy/Software/....".  By the way, if I were you, I'd choose an easier path. :-)